# Google Translate API. How many people can use my translation functionality daily?

Tags: javascript, google-translate

When I implement google translation to my multilangual site, something like in [this example](http://coderscult.com/javascript-ajax/2008/03/22/google-translate-working-example/). I expect that it will be used by thousands of people daily. Will google block it in this case? And if so, is there some alternative to google translate (with no limitations)?

Answer (score 1):

[Google Translate API Terms of Use](http://code.google.com/apis/language/translate/terms.html). Doesn't look like they would block you unless you breach certain conditions (no more than 5000 chars in length etc)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is also a daily limit of 100,000 characters per IP.

Source:
http://googlecode.blogspot.com/2010/11/introducing-google-apis-console-and-our.html?showComment=1288658965222#c1443822788531912961

and

http://www.devcomments.com/Language-translation-Daily-Limit-at1040559.htm

Couldn't find any official statement, though.